# window scroll : avoid multiple api hits based on scroll height

Tags: jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am getting data from the api hit on window scroll i.e. when user reaches 95% down on the page. The issue is multiple api hits are getting fired.

I am assuming this is due to asynchronous nature of js calls and window scroll being called multiple times for each time user scroll down.

I did put a variable 'taskFired' to check and allow api hit logic only if its not executing already. But still when user scrolls down, i am getting 4-5 api hits instead of 1. I am unable to figure out the reason.

The code looks like:

//variable to check if we are already hitting api or have reached 95% right now.By default it is false.

```
var taskFired = false;
```

//scroll event

```
$(window).scroll(function (evt) {
            if (!taskFired) { //allow to check and hit api if taskFired is false
                $.when(_self.scrollApiHit()).then(function () {
                    taskFired = false; //reset variable when api hit done
                });
            }                
        });

_self.scrollApiHit = function () {               
                var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
                var scrolltrigger = 0.95;    

                if ((wintop / (docheight - winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
                    taskFired = true;
                    //API HIT
                }
            };
```

I even tried putting setTimeout but even this is not working:

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!taskFired) {
                        $.when(_self.scrollApiHit()).then(function () {
                            taskFired = false;
                        });
                    }
                },1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `$.when` documentation states,

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when() and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

You have to make sure that `_self.scrollApiHit` actually returns a promise, otherwise, `taskFired` will be set back to `false` immediately. Your function `_self.scrollApiHit` doesn't seem to be a promise.

Could you try something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function (evt) {
        if (!taskFired) {               
            var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
            var scrolltrigger = 0.95;    

            if ((wintop / (docheight - winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
                taskFired = true;
                $.when($.ajax("API HIT HERE")).then(function () {
                    taskFired = false; //reset variable when api hit done
                });
            }
        }                
    });
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be same as putting 'taskFired = false;' in ajax success and failure callback?

Comment: Yes, it would be the same. I just copied the promise structure because you've been using it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried resetting taskFired in ajax success call after reading more about when and deferred promise.

This is what i did and it worked for me.

```
$(window).scroll(function (evt) {
                if (!taskFired) { //allow to check and hit api if taskFired is false
                    _self.scrollApiHit();
                }                
            });

_self.scrollApiHit = function () {               
                var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
                var scrolltrigger = 0.95;    

                if ((wintop / (docheight - winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
                    taskFired = true;
                    //API HIT [on success set taskFired = false]
                }
            };
```